# The neighborhood of e in a topological group

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

suppse U is an open neighborhood of e in a topological group G and how to prove there exists an open neighborhood V s. t. $V=V^{-1}$ and $V^{2}$ is a subset of U?  Another question is.how to prove the union of all powers of U is a closed subset of G?

Comment: Hi W.penny. Please only ask one question per post. Also, it's good practice to typeset your posts: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: What are your thoughts about U $\cap$ $U^{-1}?$

Comment: No open set can belong to another open set. For the question to make sense, it would be V squared is subset of V. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Hey, for the second part try to prove the general claim: In a topological group any open subgroup is closed. (Hint: Quotients partition the space).
After that, you do have an open set (a Union of open sets) just make sure its a group.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint:- the multiplication map $\mu\colon G\times G\to G$ is continuous and $\mu^{-1}(U)\ni (e,e)$, so you can find open subsets $W_1,W_2$ of $G$ both containing $e$ such that $W_1\times W_2\subseteq\mu^{-1}(U)$.  Now, what do you know about $W:=W_1\cap W_2$?  And what about $V:=W\cap W^{-1}$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hint, i have solved this problem which is taken from my homework assigned by my professor .